# Adding Shape when JFrame is created. Where to put the constructor?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcomponent

I know the below code does not work for what I'm trying to do, but I haven't found a fix for it. I am trying to add a blank rectangle to the bottom of the frame when the program runs. When I run the following code, the frame populates correctly with my labels, button, and TextFieldArea but it isn't creating the blank rectangle I am trying to add to the bottom (The end goal will be to fill the rectangle as the program works to completion aka a progress bar).

My thoughts were that you could create a subClass within my TicketCounterFrame class that would be able to extend JComponent so I could create my rectangle that way. I have a companion method called `createComponents` where I am creating the rest of my components, and then I create a panel in the constructor, add all my components to the panel, and then add the panel to the frame. I haven't worked with creating shapes and adding them to a frame at all so I'm confused on if you would need to make a private instance variable progBar of type ProgressBar and how exactly you create that component and add it to the frame along with the rest of the components created in `createComponents` method.

I'm positive I'm not thinking about this correctly but haven't been able to find helpful examples. Can someone show me how/why I'm doing this incorrectly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TicketCounterFrame extends JFrame{
    TicketCounter tickets;

    private JLabel headerLbl;
    private JLabel promptLbl;
    private JLabel soldLbl;
    private JTextField ticketAmount;
    private JButton purchaseBtn;
    private ProgressBar progBar;

public TicketCounterFrame(TicketCounter tkts){
    this.tickets = tkts;
    createComponents();

    submitClickListener s = new submitClickListener();
    purchaseBtn.addActionListener(s);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(headerLbl);
    panel.add(ticketAmount);
    panel.add(purchaseBtn);
    panel.add(promptLbl);
    panel.add(soldLbl);
    panel.add(progBar);
    add(panel);
    setSize(600,400);
}

class submitClickListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String t = ticketAmount.getText();
        try 
        {
            int ticketAmt = Integer.parseInt(t);
            if(ticketAmt <= 6 && ticketAmt > 0)
            {
                if (ticketAmt < tickets.getRemaining())
                {
                    tickets.purchaseTickets(ticketAmt);
                    ticketAmount.setText("");
                    promptLbl.setText(ticketAmt + " ticket(s) purchased. There are " + tickets.getRemaining() + " tickets remaining for sale");
                }
                else if(ticketAmt > tickets.getRemaining())
                {
                    ticketAmount.setText("");
                    promptLbl.setText("Invalid entry. There are only " + tickets.getRemaining() + " tickets left. Try again.");
                }
                else if (ticketAmt == tickets.getRemaining())
                {
                    tickets.purchaseTickets(ticketAmt);
                    ticketAmount.setText("");
                    promptLbl.setText("There are " + tickets.getRemaining() + " tickets left.");
                    soldLbl.setText("SOLD OUT!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ticketAmount.setText("");
                promptLbl.setText("Invalid entry. Try again. There are " + tickets.getRemaining() + " tickets remaining for sale");
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException err){
            ticketAmount.setText("");
            promptLbl.setText("Invalid entry. Try again. There are " + tickets.getRemaining() + " tickets remaining");
        }
    }
}

private void createComponents(){
    headerLbl = new JLabel("Enter how many tickets for purchase (1 - 6)");
    ticketAmount = new JTextField(10);
    promptLbl = new JLabel("There are " + tickets.getRemaining() + " tickets for sale");
    soldLbl = new JLabel();
    purchaseBtn = new JButton("Buy tickets");
    progBar = new ProgressBar();
}

public class ProgressBar extends JComponent{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.drawRect(100,  200,  300,  50);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, is your question "how do I add a component to the bottom of a container"? If so, then think layout managers such as BorderLayout and adding your progBar BorderLayout.PAGE_END (also known as BorderLayout.SOUTH). Also progBar needs to have an adequate preferredSize. For my money though I'd use a real JProgressBar for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align JPanel to bottom of JFrame (java swing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907307/how-to-align-jpanel-to-bottom-of-jframe-java-swing)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not using a layout manager just yet. I am using the default for JPanel, so my thinking was, since I'm adding it last to panel, that would be at the bottom by default. My issue is that I can't even get the rectangle to draw in the first place and I'm not sure how to draw a component on a frame.

Comment: `"I'm not using a layout manager just yet..."` -- and **THAT'S** your problem. No, it does not "go to the bottom by default". You in fact **are** using a layout manager without realizing it -- JPanel uses FlowLayout by default. Please read the layout manager tutorial to learn how to use them properly. And no your rectangle won't draw because of the second issue I mentioned -- your JComponent has a default preferred size of [0, 0].

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I meant that by default, you are using the FlowLayout for JPanel if you don't specify one, my fault for making that confusing. Do I set the preferred size of my component after I construct it?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783793/java-difference-between-the-setpreferredsize-and-setsize-methods-in-compone